# Unable to use the Nuget Manager in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

Getting error when i try to install in package Manager console. **Install-Package : Unable to find package 'System.Data.SQLite'**. At first, I thought that i enter the wrong package so i double check what i type in the console and I pretty sure that i entered the correct command. so I go to the Manage Nuget Package in my VS2012 and i getting also error.
[image]

my nuget settings:
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: It seems you have a network problem. Can you open https://www.nuget.org in your browser? Don't you use a proxy to connect to the internet?

Comment: @MohammadDehghan I able to access the nuget.org in my browser. I dont use proxy to connect to the internet.

Comment: does enabling TLS1.2 solve the issue?

Comment: any update on this issue? Have you enabled TLS1.2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [enable TLS 1.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client#configure-for-strong-cryptography), which is [required since june 2020](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/nuget-org-will-permanently-remove-support-for-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-june-15th/).

- start `regedit.exe`
- go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319`
- create DWORDs `SystemDefaultTlsVersions` and `SchUseStrongCrypto` and set both to `1`.

This will works since Windows 8, if you still use Windows 7, you need to [enable TLS 1.2 first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client#bkmk_winhttp).